# $\sum_{k=0}^{\min(m,n)} \binom{n}{k} \binom{m}{k}$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\min(m,n)} \binom{n}{k} \binom{m}{k}
$$
If $n$ and $m$ are given, this can be simply solved by looping from $k=0$ to $\min(n,m)$. But is there any way to simplify this expression ? I tried to express the combinations in terms of factorials, but didn't come up with something useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is ${n + m \choose n}$.  This is a case of [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity).

Comment: Thank you for your answer !